# Symfony2 CRUD Listview of Users Not Working

Tags: listview, symfony, crud

I created entity **Users** using reverse engineering and tried to create Controller and View from that entity using following command:-

```
$ php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=AcmeDemoBundle:User --format=annotation
```

It did ask me to contain "write" action, configuration format and prefix. Everything went good and two scripts generated under Controller and Views. But when i call the below url to view the list page of users then i get error:-

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/users
```

Error

```
No route found for "GET /users"
```

Does that mean once you generate CRUD, it does not add route for that entity in routing.yml or i am missing something?

Comment: Open up your User entity and check what the base route is in the annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import annoted route in routing.yml :

```
user:
resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/UserController.php"
type:     annotation
```

Then do a `php app/console router:debug` to check that the routes are available.