# Symfony2 CRUD routing Failed

Tags: symfony, routes, crud

After executing the following command for CRUD generation:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=AcmeDemoBundle:Users --format=yml
```

i get error for automatic routing update by CRUD for each entity.

```
Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]? yes
Importing the CRUD routes: FAILED


  The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
  You must do the following changes manually.


- Import the bundle's routing resource in the bundle routing file
  (C:\wamp\www\symfony\src\Acme\DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml).

    AcmeDemoBundle_categories:
        resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/categories.yml"
        prefix:   /categories
```

I also tried creating a new bundle but still gets same error. So everytime i add the above code in routing file /src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

Can someone please suggest what i am missing?

Comment: All I can think of is it's a permission issue perhaps. No read write permissions issues on it?

Comment: which folder needs to give permissions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 CRUD Listview of Users Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855094/symfony2-crud-listview-of-users-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing, not sure how to get the generation to work right but it wants you to add that code to your main routing.yml file so it can link the generated routes:

```
AcmeDemoBundle_categories:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/categories.yml"
    prefix:   /categories
```